# Python - dynamic serializers.ModelSerializer Meta class

Tags: python, django, django-serializer

I would like to create and instance this way.

```
from app.controller.Serializer import Serializer
from app.models import Stocks,Stocks2

stocks = Stocks.objects.all()
stocks2 = Stocks2.objects.all()

churchserzer = Serializer(Stocks, ('field1','field2'),stocks, many=True)
churchserzer2 = Serializer(Stocks2, ('field1','field2'),stocks2, many=True)
```

But Im confused on how should I populate the 1st and 2nd Serializer params values to its Meta class variables before creating an instance of Serializer.
Then call the parent class contructor method.
Im thinkin of implementing Serializer class this this way, but I dont know how to set Meta Class variables value from **init** .

```
class Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def __init__(self, model,fields, objects, **kwargs):
       self.model = model
       self.fields = fields

       # kwargs ( many=True )
       super().__init__(objects,kwargs)

    class Meta:
       model = self.model     
       fields = self.fields
```

Comment: What do you want to base the inclusion or exclusion of fields on?

Comment: @saad I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) to dynamically instantiate a class in python.

But I'm not sure i would recommend it, as I've tried to do the same and the result where really underwhelming. I guess it depends on your specific needs.

However, It's a good exercise to learn how to use the type builtin.

Here's an example:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from track.models import Track

Meta = type('Meta', (object,), dict(model=Track, fields=('band', 'link')))
TrackSerializer = type('TrackSerializer', (serializers.ModelSerializer,), dict(Meta=Meta))


In [2]: TrackSerializer()
Out[2]:
Serializer():
    band = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Band.objects.all())
    link = CharField(max_length=511)
```

Comment: I have updated my question to make it clear a little bit.

Comment: Thanks @Taek, I might get an idea from you code. Im waiting.

Comment: You can pretty much use `self.Meta = type(...)` in your `__init__` method, it should do the trick.

Comment: I have updated my serializer this way.. 

class Serializer:

    def __init__(self, model, fields, objects, **kwargs):
        Meta = type('Meta', (object,), dict(model=model, fields=fields))
        modelserializer = type('Serializer', (serializers.ModelSerializer,), dict(Meta=Meta))
        self.modelserializer = modelserializer(objects, kwargs)

    def getData(self):
        return self.modelserializer.data;

Comment: But Im getting an error like this 
When a serializer is passed a `data` keyword argument you must call `.is_valid()` before attempting to access the serialized `.data` representation.
You should either call `.is_valid()` first, or access `.initial_data` instead.